# Convert string to Datetime Exception for 15-07-2013

Tags: string, c#-4.0, datetime, date-conversion

I am trying to convert string to datetime. But it is giving me exceptioncontibously.
Kindly help.

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("15-07-2013");
```

I am getting exception as "**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**"

Now i have the string as "15-07-2013 07:12:00 PM"
When i am using the code as mentioned below i am getting exception.

```
 DateTime dtCurrentFile = DateTime.ParseExact("15-07-2013 07:12:00 PM", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

I am getting the same exception.

Comment: Kindly reply why i am getting exception for this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always force the format with `DateTime.ParseExact` and avoid culture issues with using `InvariantCulture`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("15-07-2013", "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

<sub>However, your code works for me with culture `"de-DE"`.</sub>

**Update**:

You have to use lower `hh` for the hours when you provide the am/pm designator:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("15-07-2013 07:12:00 PM", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
```

`HH` means 24h format which makes no sense at all with the AM/PM designator.

Comment: Kindly check the next scenario that i have pointed out.I am getting the same error.Please check question for the next part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your string format is "dd-MM-yyyy" , but `Convert.ToDateTime()` default format is **"MM-dd-yyyy"** . So Options are:

1. Changing your string format to "07/15/2013"
2. Forcing the conversion to adapt with it using:

   `DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("15-07-2013", "dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)`;

Comment: Kindly check the next scenario that i have pointed out.I am getting the same error.Please check question for the next part of the question.

Comment: _"default format is "MM-dd-yyyy""_. That is not correct, it depends on your culture. In many cultures it's `dd-MM-yyyy`, then OP's original code works without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to use ParseExact:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("15-07-2013", "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem why you are getting exception is that by default C# supports date time in this format 

"MM/dd/yyyy" where as you are trying passing date time is this format "dd-MM-yyyy" 
although you can convert using your format but for that you need to tell the compiler your date is in which format so for that you can use  
`DateTime
               myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("15-07-2013", "dd-MM-yyyy",
                                      System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`